# JS: How to detect whether cursor is in textfield

Tags: javascript, html, shortcut

I want to use some letters ( keys ) as shortcut for some actions in javascript.  I want to check whether the cursor is focused on any textfield, form input, etc. so that the shortcut action will be canceled when user is typing something in a form or textfield.

For example, i want an alert() to be executed when user presses 'A'. But if the user is typing  some text in a textarea like 'A website' then he will be pressing 'A', this time alert() should not be executed.

Comment: Though this is perfectly possibly, I propably would try and use combination of keys instead, such as `CTRL+SHIFT+A` or similar as that will less likely interfer with inputs in the first place and also won't override default browser hotkeys. If you can post the [**code you currently have**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) issues with I'm sure we can fix it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
  if ( e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT' ) return;

  handle_shortcut();
};
```

Comment: Why do you test two times on "INPUT"?

Answer (score 13):

```
$(document).keydown( function( e ) { 
  if( e.target.nodeName == "INPUT" || e.target.nodeName == "TEXTAREA" ) return;
  if( e.target.isContentEditable ) return;

  // Do stuff 
}
```

Comment: Consider adding support for [datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp).

Comment: The target of a `datalist` is still an `input` field, so this should work

Answer (score 6):

jQuery

```
$(window).bind('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input'){
        return;
    }
    alert('a');
});
```

or pure js

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input'){
        return;
    }
    alert('a');
};
```

What you can do in addition to this is define an array of non-alert element types, so `input`, `textarea` etc and then check none of those elements are currently the target.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7F3JH/

Comment: +1 for JavaScript and jQuery example. Though OP has not tagged question with jQuery it might be a viable solution for OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind and unbind the shortcut events depending on which element currently has focus on your page.

JavaScript

```
window.onload = initWindow();

function initWindow () {
    attachShortcutHandler();

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0, max = inputs.length; i < max; i++) {
        inputs[i].onfocus = removeShortcutHandler;
        intputs[i].onblur = attachShortcutHandler;
    }
}

function removeShortcutHandler () {
    window.onkeypress = null;
}

function attachShortcutHandler() {
    window.onkeypress = function () {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    initShortcutHandler();

    $('input, [any other element you want]')
        .on('focus', function () {
            $('body').off('keypress');
        })
        .on('blur', function () {
            initShortcutHandler();
        });
});

function initShortcutHandler() {
    $('body').on('keypress', function () {
       //do your stuff
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

```
 $('element').mouseover(function() {
      alert('over');
 });
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think OP is intending to know if the `caret` is currently in an `input`, meaning a control currently has focus. Question is worded loosely though.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a flag as global. and set it false when any textbox has focus.

> var flag = true;
>
> $('input:type="text").focus(function(txt) {
>        flag= false; });
>
> ---
>
> if(flag)  //shortcut keys works...

Answer (score 0):

Better use the focusOut method defined in JQuery. As per my understanding you can do something like this

```
$("input").focusout(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "A"{
   alert("your message");
   return false;
  }else{
    //do other processing here.
  }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: OP has not tagged question with jQuery so the answer should propably also contain a JavaScript only solution.